# How can I send a distribution group without others seeing their email addresses but not use bcc?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

The Marketing Manager, or HR Manager, wants to use a distribution list sending `To: All Users`... without seeing the email addresses.

I'd like to know how to do this so I can send this to the Records distribution List. I also want to know, if it is OK to send the record distribution list in the To: field together with the email address of the person whom the email is intended for?

Comment: Without talking to your HR manager, I can't be 100% sure, but I think they're using a 3rd party service like Sendgrid or Mailchimp to send such mass mailings out.

Answer (score 3):

If you enter the distributionlist in the TO field, people who receive it will see the distribution list as "to" but everyone can simply check the email addresses that are in the list and unvold the list when they open/view the message.

If you really want to hide the names (untracable) you *will* have to use BCC.

You can create a dummy record in your contacts saying "All users" with your own email address in it. You place this user in the TO field, and in the BCC you put everyone (or the distributionlist) so they're not viewable by the recipients.

BCC is the only way to prevent the people from receiving the emails to find out who else got it that are listed in the BCC.

Comment: Another way to achieve the author's goal is to use mail merge. If you don't know what a mail merge is --> A mail merge is a combined function of Word and Outlook in which you create a single message and select the addresses from Outlook. When you instruct to send the message, individual messages are created for each person so other address labels are never exposed as they were never put on it.

Comment: @zain.ali - useful addition, but very inefficient when the user already has access to the distribution list and could use BCC...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can achieve this without using BCC. This can be done with **free** [Send Messages Personally](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesSendPersonally) add-in. To use it, you just add all required recipients (or distribution list) to the "To" field and then run the utility: it will create a separate personified message for each of the recipients. Please note that I recommend this add-in because I'm one of its developers.

Comment: Will it also work if you enter a distributionlist in the `to` field? In most common organisations they already have made the list once. Setting the members for `to` each time is just too time consuming.

Comment: Yes, it will work.